# Can't create a PostgreSQL Superuser role to get an Application installed and running

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I want to install an application (Odoo) that uses PostgreSQL, but it needs you create a superuser Role to allow the aplication process instalation create its own database. I just created an Azure PostgreSQL database (PaaS), but the user it creats is not a Superuser, and can't create a superuser role. Is there a way to get my admin user a Superuser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To explain the users and roles a little better for Azure Database for PostgreSQL:

By default, when a server is created we have the following 3 roles defined, which you can also see when you run `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;` –

1. azure_pg_admin
2. azure_superuser
3. server admin login – the admin login the user created the server with – which by default is a member of azure_pg_admin.

Ours is a managed PaaS service and Microsoft is the azure_superuser. **We don’t grant superuser privileges to the user.**

With that as baseline, there is at least one role (user) at any given time that is part of azure_pg_admin group i.e. server admin login. This user can create databases, create custom roles and customize privileges, and create additional users that are member of azure_pg_admin. A user is either a part of this group or not. Any user outside this group will not have those privileges.

Hope that helps answer your question.

Saloni

Comment: What if I need to `alter system` to tune the settings for my application? Can I set e.g., `effective_cache_size`? I need superuser to do that, or the ability to update it in the server parameters. Otherwise I need to find another provider; this is a deal-breaker.

Comment: Does `azure_superuser` role can access client database tables data/objects ? do we have  restrict `azure_superuser` from accessing our tables data

Comment: It is not the best that I cannot be a superuser on any databases. There is a stuck query that I need to kill, and I need superuser access to do that. That really degrades the quality of this product offering.

Answer (score 0):

When we postgres as service then we cannot be superuser but can enable extensions allowed

Azure console => Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server =>  => Server parameters => azure.extensions =>  => Save

[image]