# Autovacuum config on Azure Postgresql

Tags: azure-database-postgresql

I am trying to change some global settings below for auto-vacuum on an Azure Database for PostgreSQL instance.

`select * from pg_settings where name like 'autovacuum%'`

Say if I want to change the scale factor with

`ALTER SYSTEM SET autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.1;`

I get 
`ERROR:  must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command
SQL state: 42501`

Is there a way to update these configuration values?

Comment: You can configure auto vacuum settings at the table level if you want. Azure  PostgreSQL auto vacuum configs are not really optimized for heavy write workloads and you may need to do manual vacuum (as the cost parameters are left at default PostgreSQL values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Stack Overflow post covers the 'superuser' role with Azure Database for PostgreSQL: [Can't create a PostgreSQL Superuser role to get an Application installed and running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654776/cant-create-a-postgresql-superuser-role-to-get-an-application-installed-and-run)

With that, and in looking at the available Server Parameters, there is no way to change the unlisted parameters or make changes that require Superuser privileges.

I suggest you go to the [Azure Database for PostgreSQL User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-postgresql) and make a recommendation.

Regards,
Mike